# updating the quantity is working only for one product

Tags: javascript, products, quantity

we have a marketplace site, where each seller/vendor have different accounts.
we are displaying products infromation in their account in frontend.
we want to provide a seller an option for editing the quantity
we are using this code : http://pastebin.com/RTYvpS0W to display the list of product name, sku , quantity.
we are using following code to edit the quantity

```
    <td>
    <?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>
    <input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $product_id;?>" name="qty" value="<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style="display:none"/>
    <span class="label wk_action">
        <img onclick="updateField('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>   
</td>


<?php $url = Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/'); ?>

<script type = "text/javascript" >

    var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();

    function updateField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId = '#qty_'+product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();

        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $url ?>', {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: $qty}
        });
    }
</script>
```

but its working only for first product, please help me what code  have to replace to work it for all products

Comment: You want a display product name & sku right

Comment: i want to update the product quantity....

Comment: login to this site : http://2.kidsdial.com/

 and check this link : http://2.kidsdial.com/index.php/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code

```
<input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $product_id; ?>" name = "qty" value = "<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>
<span class = "label wk_action">
    <img onclick = "updateField('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');
            return false;" src = "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>
```

To

```
<input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" name = "qty" value = "<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>
<span class = "label wk_action">
    <img onclick = "updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');
            return false;" src = "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>
```

Comment: now update button is working for all products.

please help me for saving the quantity in database

i am using this code in controller file: http://pastebin.com/20un3uT8

but its not working